# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.justjava.MainActivity" on path

Tags: java, android

[i tried to simulate the app but it crashes always..i turned the instant run off but,it stills crash**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9jHX.png)

Comment: Add your code for this error

Comment: have you declare your activity in manifest file?

Comment: Clean your build then run application

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by multidex;

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex